# Preventing bash $PS4 from replicating first character

Tags: bash, debugging

According to the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) (emphasis mine):

> PS4
>   The value is the prompt printed before the command line is echoed when the -x option is set (see The Set Builtin). **The first character of PS4 is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection.** The default is ‘+ ’.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I thought of cursor left (`\b`), but bash seems to only consider the literal first character (`\`).

Comment: Make it the null character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set PS4 to have its first character to be `NUL`, which takes no space on screen:

```
export PS4="\000 "
```

You will then have no visual indication of how deeply-nested the commands in question are.

Answer (score 0):

@DopeGhoti's answer did not work for me but this did

```
PS4='\033[0D'
```

It moves the cursor 0 characters to the left, so it's basically a NOOP.